# Сформировать запрос на умножение строк SQL

Tags: sql, запрос

Нужно сделать запрос, чтобы он умножал строки count и size и записывал их в total
Делаю через SELECT count * size AS total FROM param_ram, он просто выводит произведение как total, но нужно чтобы он полученный результат вставлял в столбец total[image: таблица]

Comment: для этого нужно использовать запрос UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

```
update param_pam set total = count * size
```